# how rspec creates database between specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is a bit of a naive / simple question. I'm having a hard time finding this info online. Basically, does rspec run `rake db:test:prepare` between every rspec group? Or is it between every example or model? Or does the schema get loaded once and then truncated between each. I need to add a rake task directly after this call to create a view since they are not supported in schema.rb.

Either a link or explanation would be greatly appreciated so that I know where to insert my rake task to create a view. Or whether there is a callback like rake db:test:after_prepare

thx

Answer (score 0):

when you enable transactional fixtures in your spec_helper, it does all the insertions/modifications inside a spec in a transaction and rolls them back after the test is complete.

The schema load and truncation happens only when the test environment loads. Not for every spec.

Comment: thx Vimsha - that sounds about right. Is there anyway I can make a call to execute a rake task at the beginning (ie right after the schema load)? Doesn't truncation of the tables happen every spec though?